# Can microsoft team app be used in UI suppression mode as Skype for business?

Tags: c#, lync, skype-for-business, microsoft-teams

I have WPF program as a Kiosk application using Lync sdk to make 2-way video call. I want to make similar application but using Microsoft team. The step is as below:

- kiosk app calls recipient -> recipient accepts call and sees video streaming from a person standing in front of kiosk app.
- kiosk also gets video streaming sent back from recipient and shows that on app interface.
- users at kiosk side will only see custom interface we develop, not Lync/Microsoft Teams UI.

As far as I understand for Teams, native app (kiosk) needs to call bot api and bot will call MS Graph via REST and Graph will create a call to recipient. I don't quite understand how to proceed after that:

1. How caller (kiosk) can receive video streaming from recipient?
2. How caller (kiosk) side turn on camera programmatically?

   In Lync, we will install Lync libraries and Lync client on application side, then Lync will handle this itself, so the app using Lync will create a call directly to callee.

   In Teams, it's different as the app needs to call Graph to create a call. So I am really confused how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The Lync Client SDK remote controls the Lync Client.  There is no such SDK for the teams app (the teams app is basically just a web browser, going to the teams web site is basically the same app minus the audio\video support).

So there is no way to do a UI-Suppression mode.

What you can to is control the teams app using the [Windows Automation Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/windows-automation-api-portal).  Using this API you can remote control the teams app to do what you want.

There is a bunch of applications written using this API for you to try manually like the [Microsoft Testing Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/testing-tools) or [Automation Sky](https://ddeltasolutions.000webhostapp.com/).  Once you have found how to do what you want using these tools then you need to convert your manual usage of these tools over into code to remote control the Microsoft Teams application.

I know it generally works as we have remote control the teams applications here.  The problems you will find is that the Teams application is really just a "special" web browser to display the Teams web site.  This means it can and does change A LOT.  So you remote controlling of the Teams application may break at any time.  So you may to program your solution to be as dynamic as possible so that you can update how you control the Teams application either live or as quickly as you can.